# Is the plain pointer, together with the usual operations & and *, a monad?

Tags: c++, monads

Type constructor:

```
template< typename T > T*;
```

Unit operator

```
template< typename T > T* unit( T /*or T&*/ t ) { return &t; }
```

Bind operator

```
template< typename A, typename B >
B* bind( A a, std::function<b*(a)> f )
{ return a ? f(a) : nullptr; }
```

Monad laws

```
bind( unit(x), f ) === f(x)
bind( bind(x, f1), f2 ) === auto a = f1(x); auto b = f2(a); return b;
```

Comment: If `unit` does not take an lvalue reference then you are returning a pointer to a variable hat no longer exists.

Comment: `unit = std::addressof`? Type constructor = `std::add_pointer_t`?

Comment: What is `template< typename T > T*;` supposed to be?

Comment: You'll find that pointers are really similar to the Maybe monad except not really designed for that like the `optional` implementations out there are (you know, minus the standard one, which is missing bind).

Comment: For one, the pointer is missing the `bind` operation (it arguably has `unit`). In fact, there's no `fmap` present either. Point being, you can implement it with those "usual" operations and get something like `Maybe`, but as it stands in the language, it's just not complete.

Comment: It cannot be a monad. There's no category to work in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer to T is a monad over T references not over T; an optional T is a monad over T.

This distinction is important, if missing in functional languages.  References have lifetimes, and pointers follow those lifetimes.

I agree that the lack of functions matching the traditional names is an unimportant detail; a vector space remains a vector space even if the binary addition operator isn't denoted `+`, so long as it available from context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am struggling to grasp monads (lacking appropriate mathematical background) and any comparison to C style languages is valuable.